# C++ How do i use correctly the open_slots.push_back() ? (no instance of overloaded function)

Tags: c++

I've got a problem, because i'm trying to use this code (as a dll export function):

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex thread_key;
std::vector<thread*> threads;
std::vector<uint32_t*> open_slots;

double thread_free(double index) {
    thread_key.lock();

    if (threads.size() > index && threads[index] != NULL) {
        if (threads[index]->joinable()) {
            threads[index]->join();
        }

        delete threads[index];
        threads[index] = NULL;
        //open_slots.push_back((uint32_t) index);
        open_slots.push_back(index);
    }

    thread_key.unlock();
    return 1;
}
```

The trouble is that the specific "open_slots.push_back(index);" is not entirely valid... so, how do i make it valid? Because VS is throwing me an error like: 'no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [con _Ty=uint32_t *, _Alloc=std::allocator<uint32_t *>]" '

Thanks myself beforehand :D .

Edit: Why double? because i'm calling from other program that only admits to call functions with double and void* (that void is a char) so... it's needed that way.

Comment: Why are you using `double` as index?

Comment: What is `open_slots`? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Ok, it was updated, i was figuring out how to put the rest of the code being inside of the code sample :) .

Comment: You still haven't provided the definition of `open_slots`.  From the error message it looks like it's something like `std::vector<uint32_t *>`?  As stated in other comments, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Well, now i've added the thing i was missing, sorry, i'm pretty new to ask about c++ code.

Comment: Oh, so useful, that i really answered myself hahahah

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer was to convert it to uint32_t, following these changes:

```
uint32_t* in = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&index);
open_slots.push_back(in);
```

That was it.